# Node.js: Exports Module Not Working

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I have this at fwdCallToAgent.coffee:

```
exports.fwdCallToAgent = (phone,res,req) ->
```

and on server.coffee:

```
fwdCallToAgent = require './lib/fwdCallToAgent'
```

and when I run fwdCallToAgent I get:

```
2011-11-13T09:49:08+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: object is not a function
```

What am I missing here?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

`require` returns the `exports` property of the required module.

What you need is either one of the following

A)

```
// fwdETC.coffee
module.exports.fwdETC = function () { ... }; 

// server.coffee
fwdETC = require('./lib/fwdETC').fwdETC
```

B)

```
// fwdETC.coffee
module.exports = function () { ... };

// server.coffee
fwdETC = require './lib/fwdETC'
```

Personally, I recommend the second approach if it's the only exported function in the module.

Comment: Jan is correct. Using CoffeeScript's destructuring assignment syntax, you can also write `{fwdCallToAgent} = require './lib/fwdCallToAgent'`.

Comment: @Jan Kuca thanks. However, when I use B) with module.exports = (phone,res,req) -> 
 User.find {account_id: phone.account_id }, (err, user) -> - it doesn't recognize "User".

Comment: Well, that's a different problem. Have you required the module where `User` is defined in in the fwdCallToAgent module? `var User = require('./user');`